# Vue JS Props are undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to use props in my methods in Vue.js

```
<login opendiv="password" rid="123"></login>
```

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    props: {
        opendiv: String,
        rid: String,
    },
    components: {
        'login': {
            data() {
                return {
                    mode: this.opendiv,
                    email: "",
                    username: "",
                    password: "",
                    confirmPassword: "",
                }
            },
            template: `<div>
            
              ...
            </div>`,
            mounted() {
                console.log(this.opendiv, this.rid);
            },
```

mode and the console.log always return undefined

Comment: you need to declare `props` property on "login" component instead of the root component: `props: [ "opendiv", "rid"]`

Comment: That worked!   If you want credit put it as an answer.